# Need to troubleshoot Bigtable read latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

We have a GKE containerised Internet facing application serving the incoming traffic/request to Bigtable via a load balancer (ssl termination at Nginx). Requests are synchronous in nature.
We are using C++ Bigtable client library to interact with Bigtable.
See-  https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp

Most of the "GET" calls are taking 40-50ms which seems to be quite unusual. I have investigated the Bigtable "Key Visualizer Tool" as well and don't see any issue with Rowkey and schema.

In order to confirm that Bigtable is working fine from the Pod, I ran a sample 'hello world' and tried to fetch the response for the sample Rowkeys synchronously and most of the "GET" calls are taking 4-5ms. Now, I'm quite unsure that what is making the "GET" calls over same Rowkeys take so long to return the response if called via application.

Network latency was something to consider but then it would delay the response time for the sample Python 'Hello World" code as well. Also, Bigtable cluster and GKE nodes are in same zone.

Any idea what areas should I be looking into for troubleshooting the same?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that comes to mind is the initial overhead to create a `bigtable::Table` object.  Are you caching the object between requests?  Would it be possible to do so?

A second area would be authentication, though I assume you are using the same authentication method for both the Python 'Hello World' and the C++ application?

If this is not helpful, reach out to me, my email address should be easy to discover from the GitHub site.

Comment: Gap between two consecutive GET calls can also be a factor, no? Sample Python 'Hello World' code doesn't offer any gap between two consecutive reads but the actual application has a gap of 4-5ms between two consecutive reads. Not sure if this gap can have such a significant impact causing the latency upto 40-50ms. Thoughts?

Comment: I was able to follow your first suggestion to cache the table object. Ran the application on VM and got 10-12ms of latency for each Rowkeys but on GKE cluster I still see the latency of 45-50ms. Please suggest for GKE.

Comment: > Not sure if this gap can have such a significant impact causing the latency upto 40-50ms. Thoughts?


I do not think it would, much longer "gaps" (say 1 hour) could as the tokens would be invalid and need to be refreshed, and the sockets may have disconnected>

As to the GKE effect: I am out of ideas. Can you open a ticket with support?

Comment: Is this a fair assumption to say that there might be compatibility issues between Bigtable C++ client library and GKE? Python code is doing great while interacting with Bigtable from GKE pod. Puzzled to learn that the same piece of C++ code is also working fine on VM but giving a hard time on GKE.

Comment: Without understanding what is going on I cannot say what is the problem, maybe it is "compatibility", maybe it is configuration issues (the Python defaults may be better for GKE than the C++ defaults), maybe the C++ and Python code are not as similar as they may appear.

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug for us (google) to track this down:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/5697

Comment: Sorry I could not reply earlier I ran our latency benchmarks in GKE and GCE and the numbers are fairly similar. More details on the bug.  If you have time to help us troubleshoot that would be great, but without more information I will close the bug.